# jquery validate show multiple errors

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-validate

I'm tring to use jquery validate to show some errors returned from the server.

I'm using the validator.showErrors() method to do this.

I can get the method to work as per the example [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors#errors).

```
var validator = $("#myform").validate();
validator.showErrors({"firstname": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!"});
```

What I'm trying to achieve however is to have 2 or more validation errors for the same or different fields. According to the documentation this is possible

> Show the specified messages. Keys have to refer to the names of
>   elements, values are displayed for those elements, using the
>   configured error placement.
>
> Arguments:
>
> errors `Object<String, String>`
>        One or more key/value pairs
>   of input names and messages.

Looking inside the showErrors method shows the following:

```
    showErrors: function(errors) {
        if(errors) {
            // add items to error list and map
            $.extend( this.errorMap, errors );
            this.errorList = [];
            for ( var name in errors ) {
                this.errorList.push({
                    message: errors[name],
                    element: this.findByName(name)[0]
                });
            }
            // remove items from success list
            this.successList = $.grep( this.successList, function(element) {
                return !(element.name in errors);
            });
        }
        this.settings.showErrors
            ? this.settings.showErrors.call( this, this.errorMap, this.errorList )
            : this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
```

I have tried the following:

```
validator.showErrors({ "Id": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!" },{ "Id":"test2"});
```

but it still only shows the first error.

Any idea the correct format to use to get it to show multiple errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it would appear the correct format is

```
validator.showErrors({ "Id": ["I know that your firstname is Pete", "test2" ]});
```

Unfortunately the second error is shown right next to the first error, so my next issue is to find a nicer way to format these.

Comment: this array syntax gives me an error, if you have the time I'd be interested to see a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: great, it turns out this functionality works using jquery >= 1.8.2 but will throw a javascript exception on jquery <= 1.7.2 (which is what I was using)